# How to set date for calendar using date picker and wpcontrol calendar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing calendar,for that I am using wpcontrol calendar and (windows phone control)datepicker and how to set a date in calendar when I changed date in datepicker.

xaml code:

```
            <wpControls:Calendar  x:Name="Cal   ColorConverter="{StaticResource ColorConverter}"MonthChanged="Cal_MonthChanged" MonthChanging="Cal_MonthChanging" SelectionChanged="Cal_SelectionChanged" DateClicked="Cal_DateClicked"/>
```

xaml datepicker:

```
          <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="Datepicker1" ValueChanged="DatePicker_ValueChanged" Margin="16,145,8,-227" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

c sharp:

I just tried one static new date for calendar.

```
 private void DatePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
  Cal.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2012, 2, 1);
}
```

Comment: Hi, please paste the code you're struggling with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" ValueChanged="datePicker_ValueChanged"/>
                <wpControls:Calendar x:Name="calender"></wpControls:Calendar>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

CS:

```
private void datePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (datePicker != null)
    {
           calender.SelectedDate = datePicker.Value.Value.Date;
           calender.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes,thanks for your response...  It selected the day what we ve picked in the datepicker but we ve to go manually to search that selected date in calndar, But I am in need of when i picked day, once I finished the date picker task, the wp calendar should appear what I ve selected in the datepicker...

Comment: its is the same you asked. when you would pick date from datepicker, it would get selected to your calender. just recheck your question what you have asked and now you are enhancing your neeeds. Please be clear what you are asking.

Comment: oh sorry for trouble, I am not explicitly mentioned in my question, But I am in need. Please read the question again "how to set a date in calendar when I changed date in datepicker". I think set is similar to appear.